# Taking data from an array to table rows and column using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, html-table

Hello everyone I am having the problem of putting array data into the table columns and rows using jquery check my code here http://jsfiddle.net/Reginald/xs5bnz3g/1/
my jquery code is like this

```
firttd = ["try error catch","Checkers","2015-04-14","2015-04-30"];//wanna

//put this on the table td and tr

var tbody = $('tbody #firstraw'),
var tr = $('<tr>');
$.each(firttd, function(i, prop) {

    $('<td>').html(firttd).appendTo(tr);  
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes and you're done with it

```
firttd = ["try error catch","Checkers","2015-04-14","2015-04-30"];
var tbody = $('tbody#firstraw'), tr = $('<tr>'); // no need of `var` keyword again after , (comma)
                               ^^^  
$.each(firttd, function(i, prop) {
    $('<td/>').html(prop).appendTo(tr);  // use prop instead of firsttd array
       ^^^^         ^^^
    $('<td/>').appendTo(tr);
});
tbody.append(tr);
```

And note: You are using `$(<td>)` but use `$(<td/>)`  instead and remove space between `$('tbody#firstraw')`

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xs5bnz3g/16/)

Comment: You can put `$('<td>').appendTo(tr);` after each `td` append to align with header label. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xs5bnz3g/14/)